# Is there a way I can give players enchanted items and armor in MCPE with commands?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am making a minigame and want to be able to give players enchanted items by the click of a button. I know how to use `/give` but can you also enchant it?

I have tried this:

```
/give @p diamond_sword 1 0 {ench:[{id:17,lvl:2},{id:19,lvl:2}]}
```

If it does not work I can just have them click buttons while holding the items.

Comment: I have tried this /give @p bow 1 0 {ench:[{id:51,lvl:1},{id:34,lvl:3}]}

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, json only supports CanPlaceOn and CanDestroy functions for adventure and you can give yourself enchanted items only with custom mods. I hope Mojang is working on this...

Answer (score 1):

As of 1.1.3, there is no way you can use the `/give` command to give already enchanted items as you can't edit the NBT tag.

However, you could connect the button to multiple command blocks. One of them would say `/give @p diamond_sword`. The other ones would say `/enchant @p smite 2` and `/enchant @p knockback 2`.

I’m assuming the ids you’ve given are for the Java Edition, because the ids for PE are different and id 19 in PE is power, which is not available on a sword. Smite on PE is 10 and knockback is 12. A list of all the ids can be found on the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#Summary_of_enchantments).

NOTE: The `/enchant` commands won’t work if the player is not holding the dimaond sword.

Comment: yes, but `Although /enchant enforces maximum levels and compatibility, other commands (such as /give, /replaceitem, and /data) can bypass these restrictions.`

Comment: @Michael The last time I tried, that doesn't work on PE/BE.

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `/replaceitem entity [Player/@p/@a/@e/@r/@s] slot.weapon.mainhand 0 diamond_sword`
Then after do `/enchant @p -enchantment-`

Answer (score 0):

You could clone a dispenser of the enchanted item of your liking and have a command block triggering dispenser as well as teleporting that item to `@p`. A little harder to set up then a single command but an easy way to not have to use `/enchant` in case they switch what they are holding on accident

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure that's possible, unless you change an items ID

Comment: How do you do that. I am not very good with commands.

Comment: If you cannot answer, **PLEASE DON'T ANSWER.**

Answer (score -3):

Yes! I think I've found the solution! It might not work though, but here :

> /give @p diamond_sword 1 0 {tag:{ench:[{id:10,lvl:1},{id:12,lvl:1}]}}

Comment: PE does not have NBT data. If it did and matched the structure of JE, that would not work because the NBT data for `/give` already starts in the `tag` compound.

Comment: Same to do with Skylinerw... I've tried everything, de-compiling MCPE's data and trying to type stuff like that in commands, using caps and no-caps, strings and no-strings, but to no avail. Looks like we'll just have to wait until it comes in a future update. Expect it soon though, as the next update is major.

Comment: it's been over 2 years, did it happen?